# What dependencies for JAX-RPC web services in Weblogic 12?

Tags: java, maven, weblogic, dependency-management, jax-rpc

I really should be able to work this out but I've failed so far.

I have an Weblogic 8.1 web service, implemented as an EJB. I'm following the steps here: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLUPG/upgrade_ws.htm#WLUPG335 to upgrade it to a JAX-RPC web service so it can be deployed in Weblogic 12c.

Code changes are done but when I compile (with maven) the Java files, I get errors about the annotation symbols not found (@WebService, @WebMethod etc.)

I've tried what feels like about 1000 options for the dependencies that are required in the POM, but without success.

So can someone explain what I need here?